# What is the appropriate manner to return a struct from a called function to a calling function in C++?

Tags: c++, function, struct, return

I have a function which takes in two int values, does some processing and then returns the processed values in the form of a struct to the calling function.

**The following is my called function:**

```
auto start_end(){
bool cond = false;
int xd = 0;
int yd = 0;
std::cout<<("Please enter a desired x coordinate")<<std::endl;

std::cin>>xd;
while(std::cin.fail()){
   std::cout<<("That is not a valid integer. Please enter a valid x co-ordinate")<<std::endl;
   std::cin.clear();
   std::cin.ignore(256,'\n');
   std::cin>>xd;
   }
   std::cout<<("Please enter a desired y coordinate")<<std::endl;

std::cin>>yd;
while(std::cin.fail()){
   std::cout<<("That is not a valid integer. Please enter a valid y co-ordinate")<<std::endl;
   std::cin.clear();
   std::cin.ignore(256,'\n');
   std::cin>>yd;
   }
struct xy{int x_received; int y_received;};
return xy{xd,yd};
}
```

We can see that the struct xy returns two values xd, yd in the above function start_end().

**The following is my calling function:**

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
std::cout <<("A-Star-Algorithm for Project 2 obstacle map")<<std::endl;
int x_start = 0;
int y_start = 0;
int init_point = start_end();


return 0;
}
```

So when I try to store the return values xd, yd in the variable init_point, I get the error:

```
No viable conversion from 'xy' to 'int'
```

Since, I got this error I tried to write the receiving variable as a 2 - index array:

```
int init_point[2] = start_end();
```

When I try to do in this way, I get the following error:

```
 Array initializer must be an initializer list
```

**My exact question :** What is the appropriate manner in which I have to receive the values xd and yd returned by function start_end() when it is called inside function int main() ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move your `struct` into a place that can be seen by `start_end` and `main`:

```
struct xy { int x; int y; };
xy start_end()
{
    ...
    return { xd, yd };
}
int main()
{
}
```

Then you can either assign it with `auto` or use the type name `xy`:

```
int main()
{
    auto xy1 = start_end();
    xy xy2 = start_end();
}
```

Or you can use [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) or [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple).

Comment: Note that you can write and use `auto xy1 = start_end();` even with OP's original placement of the struct definition.  But I believe it is considered better style to do as you suggest

Answer (score 2):

[`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) is to your relief ([live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NO1xt2d6J7e341Gx))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

auto start_end() {
  auto x = 1, y = 2;
  return std::make_tuple(x, y);
}

int main() {
  int x, y;
  std::tie(x, y) = start_end();
  std::cout << x << ' ' << y << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Since C++17 it can also be written `auto [x, y] = start_end();`

Comment: @M.M Wow, that's neat! Could you point me to some references (e.g., cppref pages) about this feature?